# Installing latest version of Angular ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I'm trying to get the latest version (0.13.0) of the [angular-bootstrap repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap).

I normally would `npm install`, but the [angular-bootstrap npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap) is still at version 0.12.0.

So I tried to install the latest commit from GitHub with `npm install --save-dev git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.git#4c6e0`, which was successful.

I then ran `npm show angular-bootstrap version`. However that returned `0.12.0`, instead of `0.13.0` as expected.

There is another package called [bootstrap-angular-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-npm), but I'm not sure if that's the right one for me.

Can anyone help me figuring out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Flash-downvoter cares to explain their decision?

Comment: Go to the node_modules folder and look for the change that happened in the last commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not totally clear about this. What I ended up doing, which is suiting me fine is installing the [angular-bootstrap-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-npm) package.

Comment: How do you "install" Css ?? Do they mean copy the files over? If so, great.... Where? or am I missing something here. The Docs only say the following.....The only required dependencies are:

    Angular (requires Angular version 2 or higher, tested with 2.0.0)
    Bootstrap CSS (tested with 4.0.0-alpha.6)

Installation

After installing the above dependencies, install ng-bootstrap via:

Answer (score -1):

Set up a `bower.json` file and specify the bootstrap version that you want to install.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
     "angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0", 
  },
  "authors": [
    "abcd"
  ],

}
```

Do a `bower install` from the command prompt

Comment: It helps you to automate installing dependencies